# How to pause and restart a NetStream object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, netstream, netconnection

I have a NetStream object, based upon the following code:

```
streamID = "mystreamkey";
videoURL = "rtmp://mystreamurl";

vid = new Video();

nc = new NetConnection();

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnectionStatus);
nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{}, streamConnected: streamConnected, streamDisconnected: streamDisconnected };
nc.connect(videoURL);

...

metaListener = new Object();
metaListener.onMetaData = received_Meta;
netStreamObj.client = metaListener;

netStreamObj.play(streamID);
vid.attachNetStream(netStreamObj);
addChild(vid);
```

All this is working fine, and I can also use `netStreamObj.pause()` to pause the live stream.

But how do I restart it? `netStreamObj.play()` won't work - it requires one parameter, so then I wrote this:

```
netStreamObj.play(streamID);
vid.attachNetStream(netStreamObj);
```

But this isn't working either.

How do I restart the stream, so that it connects to the live stream it was previously connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I restart the stream, so that it connects to the live stream it
>   was previously connected to?

For future reference, check the NetStream API **[documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html)** for options. You'll be looking to check out the commands listed under the **[Public methods](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#methodSummary)** section.

You can use either :

> **[resume():](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#resume())** Resumes playback of a video stream that is paused.

usage : `netStreamObj.resume();`

> **[togglePause():](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#togglePause())** Pauses or resumes playback of a stream.

usage : `netStreamObj.togglePause();` 


I suggest using `togglePause`since it **auto-detects** the playback state of the NetStream object. Your "Pause" button (or MovieClip) should simply have a click listener event whose function has this line : `netStreamObj.togglePause();`. It's that easy...